# How to build CPython with static libbz2

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, cpython, bzip2

I've been trying to build CPython with static libs so as to port it into another machine. I've managed to make it work, it compiles fine and is accessible from the other machine. But the moment I try to execute a module that requires bz2 it fails because it cannot find the libbz2.so

I compile Python with:

```
./configure --prefix=/prj/build/python --enable-shared=no --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a" CFLAGS="-fPIC"
make && make install
```

As you can see, I've been trying to make the configure use the static lib already. I have installed the library with apt-get install libbz2-dev. It works well for libffi but not for libbz2. It goes straight for the .so instead.

I've read [somewhere else](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically) people suggest using "-static" as flag. But that makes everything static which I don't want. I only need those two built-in modules static.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you test more carefully you'll find that your attempt
to statically link `libffi` and `libbz2` is actually ineffectual in *both* cases.

The python3 extension module that interfaces to `libffi` is `cyctpes`.
The module that interfaces to `libz2` is of course `bz2`. If you write a
minimal python script that calls into `cyctpes`
and another that calls into `bz2`, then run each script with the python3 interpreter you've built
in this way:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=libs /prj/build/python/bin/python3 <testscript>.py
```

then setting `LD_DEBUG=libs` in the shell will prompt the runtime linker to
display information about each shared library that is loaded to run the program. You'll
see that the `bz2` module tester dynamically loads `libbz2.so` and also that the `ctypes` tester
dynamically loads `libffi`, which you aim to avoid.

**Your** `./configure...`  **command misses the mark**

The setting `LD_FLAGS= ... -l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a` that
you passed to `./configure` fails to link against those libraries in the builds of the
`ctypes` and `bz2` modules and links with the default shared libraries instead.
If we run your build and capture the build log, we can see that this is so and why.

For the `ctypes` module, the link step output is:

```
gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a  \
   Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.o \
   Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.o Modules/_ctypes/callproc.o \
   Modules/_ctypes/stgdict.o \
   Modules/_ctypes/cfield.o \
   -lffi  -ldl  -o Modules/_ctypes.cpython-313-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

For the `bz2` module, the link step output is:

```
gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a \        
    Modules/_bz2module.o \
    -lbz2  -o Modules/_bz2.cpython-313-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Notice first that in both cases the `LDFLAGS` value you have input to `./configure`, i.e.

```
-L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a
```

precedes all the object files to be linked.

Notice also that the default libraries for the these linkages - the ones that you are trying to knock with `-l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a` -
are still in the linkages, but they come after all the object files. In the `bz2` linkage,
`-lbz2` is there, after the object files. And in the `ctypes` linkage `-lffi` is there, after the
object files.

That's probably what you expected, expecting the default shared libaries to be knocked out by
the static ones that you have placed before them. But remember how the linker resolves symbols?

- It scans the sequence of input files - explicitly named object files,
  explicitly named libraries and `-l`-libraries discovered by search - just once from left to
  right.
- It unconditionally links any object file but it searches a library only to find definitions of
  undefined symbol references that have accrued earlier in the linkage.
- When a static library member, e.g. `libffi.a(objfile.o)`, is found to provide a needed definition
  then the object file `objfile.o` is copied out of the archive and statically linked into the output file.
- When a shared library, e.g. `libffi.so` is found to provide a needed definition then the linker just
  drops a note into the output file that will prompt the *dynamic* linker at runtime to load the necessary shared library
  and try to resolve remaining undefined symbols against it - that remainder being the symbols that could not be
  statically defined from the object files linked at buildtime.

When the `cytypes` and `bz2` modules are linked as above, `-l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a` specify
the very first two files that the linker encounters. They are both libraries. Since nothing
at all has so far been linked into the output file, there are 0 undefined symbol references to
resolve, and therefore nothing to search for in libraries. `libffi.a` and `libbz2.a` contribute
nothing to the linkage at this point and are never considered again.

After `libffi.a` and `libbz2.a` are ignored, the linker finds the object files and links them
all into the output file. That brings undefined symbol references into the linkage and obliges
the linker to seach subsequent libraries for definitions. Next come the default `-l` options that
you wanted to knock out, `-lffi` for the `ctypes` module and `-lbz2` for the `bz2` module. We are
not doing a `-static` linkage, so the linker will for preference resolve these `-l` options to the shared libraries
`libffi.so` and `libbz2.so`. Which it duly does, and finds needed definitions in them. So
they are added to the dynamic dependencies of the respective modules, just as they would by default.

**Why your** `./configure` **command makes that mistake**

Your `./configure` command results in `-l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a` being interpolated into
linkage commands in a position where it has no effect. This stems from a misunderstanding of
the autotools linkage environment variables `LD_FLAGS` and `LIBS`. Their proper roles are
clarified by running `./configure (-h|--help)` in the build directory (of any autotooled package)
and looking for those variables in the section `Some influential environment variables:`

```
Some influential environment variables
  ...[cut]...   
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  ...[cut]...
```

`$LD_FLAGS` is interpolated into linkage commands *before* the object files are consumed,
`$LIBS` after them. This distinction lets you avoid interpolating `-l`-options uselessly
before the object files.

**The obvious fix - and why it is a loser**

It seems obvious that your `./configure` command should define:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" LIBS="-l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a"
```

to put `-l:libffi.a` and  `-l:libbz2.a` in a linkage position where they matter.

But this is ineffective in a different way. If you build like that and save the buildlog,
you'll now see that whereas previously `-l:libffi.a -l:libbz2.a` appeared uselessly in the linkage of every module,
now they will appear in the linkage of none.

Once again, `./configure -h` explains.

```
Some influential environment variables:
...[cut]...
  LIBFFI_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for LIBFFI, overriding pkg-config
  LIBFFI_LIBS linker flags for LIBFFI, overriding pkg-config
...[cut]...
  BZIP2_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for BZIP2, overriding pkg-config
  BZIP2_LIBS  linker flags for BZIP2, overriding pkg-config
...[cut]...
```

All of the extension module builds depend on upstream libraries whose package maintainers
define the compilation and linkage options that downstream builds require. These
options are expressed in the *library*.`pc` file that comes with the library's development
package and is installed in the like of `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/`. There,
the `pkg-config` tool can retrieve and query them with commands like<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags libffi
# ...Nothing
$ pkg-config --libs libffi
-lffi
```

The `./configure -h` output shows that the python3 build will source
the `LIBS` value for linking with any of the upstream extension module libraries
`LIBNAME` from the expansion of `$(LIBNAME_LIBS)`, if `LIBNAME_LIBS` is
defined, and by default source it from the expansion of `$(pkg-config --libs LIBNAME)`
(Since python3 does not build these upstream libraries, `LIBNAME_CFLAGS` is
irrelevant.)

This is just as it should be. But it means that the `./configure`-ed value of `LIBS`
is unused in the extension module builds.

**The correct** `./configure ...` **command - and why even that is insufficent**

To replace the `LIBS` values sourced from `pkg-config` in the module builds for
`ctypes` and `bz2`, your `./configure` command should pass:

```
LIBFFI_LIBS=-l:libffi.a BZIP2_LIBS=-l:libbz2.a
```

If you build on that basis, you'll get conclusive proof that `libffi.a` and `libbz2.a` have been used - because when either of these libraries is used in a `-shared` linkage
the build will fail with a relocation linkage error, like:

```
gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu     Modules/_bz2module.o -l:libbz2.a  -o Modules/_bz2.cpython-313-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): warning: relocation against `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `BZ2_crc32Table' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

That happens because the packaged static libraries contain object files, like `libbz2.a(bzlib.o)`, that have not been compiled as
position independent code (`-fPIC`). They can't be linked into a shared library, which must be PIC; they're not intended for `-shared` linkage.

Passing `CFLAGS=-fPIC` in you own `./configure` command can't fix this, because `-fPIC` is a compilation option, and you are not compiling the non-PIC object files in your static libraries, you're just trying to link them `-shared`. The relocation error diagnostic:

```
...libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `BZ2_crc32Table' \
can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

is telling you that the object file `libbz2.a(bzlib.o)` needs to be recompiled `-fPIC`. But you haven't got the source code.

**What else you need to do for success**

So before you fix the `./configure` command for the python3 build, you first need to get the source
packages for `bzip2` and `libffi` and build local static libraries `libbz2.a` and `libff1.a` specifying `-fPIC` in the
`CFLAGS`.

It looks as if `/usr/local/lib64` is where you want local libraries, so you could install your `-fPIC` static libraries there.
Maybe rename them `libbz2-PIC.a` and `libff1-PIC.a` for clarity and amend your python3 `./configure` commandline accordingly.

You'll then be able to build python3 successfully and the `LD_DEBUG=libs` test will show you that the `bz2` module does not
load `libbz2.so` and the the `ctypes` module does not load `libffi.so`

---

1. It's a [long-standing bug in Debian-derived distros](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=853803) and maybe others that the
   `libbz2-dev` source package lacks a `pkg-config` `.pc` file. In this case the python3 build just goes ahead with `-lbz2` to link the
   libary.